# Can someone help me with how to group by the incidents in this data for each day

Tags: google-sheets

| datetime | instance_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 7:09:10 UTC | 9e27bf765fdc2986c2f92c6919872380 |
| 2022-04-12 7:07:59 UTC | d96f725b82f1c12f177e9d1b9c1bb643 |
| 2022-04-12 7:07:50 UTC | f9b959ce7f71a1f92bcbf0a35502a036 |
| 2022-04-12 7:04:32 UTC | 7d2d079987017cf300ad30d97ddaad84 |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:56 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:53 UTC | 53f113f131c5b49c98714600b95fddb3 |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:50 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:22 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:17 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:00 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 7:01:00 UTC | 2a0442055d31f3b75b860cd86aecf4ea |
| 2022-04-12 7:00:27 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 6:59:15 UTC | 188a4318617bae847690254706106891 |
| 2022-04-12 6:58:53 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 6:58:47 UTC |  |
| 2022-04-12 6:58:36 UTC | 7068d8135b7d792554d60c3046848af7 |
| 2022-04-12 6:58:25 UTC | c7696a1b1a3dd8d5ee13cfc7c84378c4 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question should actually include a "question" in addition to example data. 
To get it reopened, please [edit it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171149/edit) to include the problem you are experiencing, what formulas you tried and what didn't work.  Please take [the Tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) and also review [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To get daily counts of incidents, extract the date portion of timestamps and use `query()` to count incidents grouped by date, like this:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { 
    to_date(iferror(value(regexextract(to_text(A1:A), "(.+?) ")), A1:A)), 
    B1:B 
  }, 
  "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd' ", 1 
) )
```

| date_time | count instance_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 | 9 |

To count all rows instead of counting non-null incidents only, count timestamps instead of incidents:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { 
    to_date(iferror(value(regexextract(to_text(A1:A), "(.+?) ")), A1:A)), 
    B1:B 
  }, 
  "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd' ", 1 
) )
```

| date_time | count date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 | 17 |

To get hourly counts, include the hour digits in extraction:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { 
    query(iferror(value(regexextract(to_text(A1:A), "(.+? \d\d?):") & ":00:00"), A1:A), "format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' ", 0), 
    B1:B 
  }, 
  "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'date and hour' ", 1 
) )
```

| date and hour | count instance_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 06:00 | 3 |
| 2022-04-12 07:00 | 6 |